# sqlfluff newline between keywords

Tags: sql, sqlfluff

I am trying to configure a rule with SQLFluff that forces you not to use whitelines between keywords.

This is the wrong code, which should give an error while using sqlfluff:

```
SELECT

 *

FROM source

LEFT JOIN another_source
```

This is the right code:

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM source
LEFT JOIN another_source
```

Can someone help me how to do this?